# Term for words that introduce a new sentence

Tags: english, terminology, cross-linguistic

I'm curious if there is a decided term for the words that begin a new utterance. They often are written with a comma following them such as below:
"Well, ..." "So, ..." but the class of these words isn't restricted to single words or a particular set and can be expanded to include other parts of speech also for example: "George, ..." is there a name for these forms?

Comment: There are several ways to refer to such words/phrases, one of them is discourse markers.

Comment: @Alex B gives the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a category of words called [transition words](https://msu.edu/~jdowell/135/transw.html) which contains your examples.